# How to create a table inside of a procedure in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, create-table

I want to create a table inside of a procedure. I tried to put the create query in a string then execute immediate the string. For example:

```
create or replace procedure hr.temp is
   var1 varchar2(4000);
begin
   var1:='create table hr.temp(
          id number)';
   execute immediate var1;
end temp;
```

But when I execute this procedure I get the error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.TEMP", line 6
> .
> .
> .

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** create procedures in the SYS account. Don't do it. Ever. (Once you move that procedure to a proper account: inside a dynamic SQL you must not specify the `;` character. Execute immediate can execute only a single statement anyway, so no termination character is required)

Comment: due to your suggestion i changed it to hr schema,but the result is the same

Comment: i removed the  `;` character,now when i execute the procedure,it begin but never end,it's like procedure is in the loop that never end!

Comment: Your example still includes the `;`. Btw: you can't create a table with the same name as an existing procedure. But apart from that this should work fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37847/2

Comment: i changed the name of table and procedure to temp2 but it still get trap in the loop

Comment: @jalalrasooly The name of procedure and table should be distinct, not the same. Did you change both to `temp2`?

Comment: yes. i changed both table and procedure to temp2

Comment: If you change **both** names to `temp2` you again wind up with two objects with the same name. Don't do that. Choose two **different** names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this. It should work...

```
create or replace procedure hr.temp is
   var1 varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   var1:='create table hr.temp2(
          id number)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var1;
end temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer of m.r 'a_horse_with_no_name' is right. The first point is I should not create a table in sys schema.

The second point is in a dynamic sql I should not use `;` character in dynamic sql.